# How to call method if I have method name as string

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

My requirement is on phase change I have to construct method names and call the methods and subsequent methods also,here I am able to construct method name but it is as String and not able to call the method. I have followed some of the suggestion given but I couldn't achieve. Please help.

```js
var previousPhase = $("#currentPhase").val();
var projectPhaseArray = ["requirement", "design", "construction", "testing", "release"];

var i = 0;
$("#currentPhase").change(function() {
    alert(previousPhase);
    i=projectPhaseArray.indexOf(previousPhase);
    for (i; i < projectPhaseArray.length; i++) {
        alert(projectPhaseArray[i]);
        var phaseTimeLineToCall = 
        projectPhaseArray[i].concat("PhasePhaseTimeLines");
        executeFunctionByName(phaseTimeLineToCall,window);
    }
});

function executeFunctionByName(functionName, context /*, args */) {
    return context[functionName].apply(context);
}

function requirementPhaseTimeLines(){
    alert("In RequirementPhaseTimelines");
}

function designPhaseTimeLines(){
    alert("In DesignPhaseTimelines");
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: maybe you'd like to use something like [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

Comment: What problem do you encounter? As for me, your `executeFunctionByName` function works fine

Answer (score 0):

**Strings don't mutate**, so you need to save the value back

```
projectPhaseArray[i] = projectPhaseArray[i].concat("PhasePhaseTimeLines");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a javascript object where you store the function name as key and the function reference as value

```
var lookup = {
    requirementPhaseTimeLines: requirementPhaseTimeLines,
    designPhaseTimeLines: designPhaseTimeLines
}
```

## Without Arguments

We have to modify `executeFunctionByName` slightly

```
function executeFunctionByName(functionName, lookup) {
    return lookup[functionName]()
}
```

#### Working Example

```js
function requirementPhaseTimeLines() {
    return "In RequirementPhaseTimelines"
}

function designPhaseTimeLines() {
    return "In DesignPhaseTimelines"
}

var lookup = {
    requirementPhaseTimeLines: requirementPhaseTimeLines,
    designPhaseTimeLines: designPhaseTimeLines
}

function executeFunctionByName(functionName, lookup) {
    return lookup[functionName]()
}

console.log(
    executeFunctionByName("requirementPhaseTimeLines", functions)
)

console.log(
    executeFunctionByName("designPhaseTimeLines", functions)
)
```

## With Arguments

If we want to pass in arguments we have to [curry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) the functions we want to let execute.

```
function greet(word) {
  return function(name) {
    return word + ', ' + name + '.'
  }
}
```

Second, we have to create a function where we can iterate trough the arguments and set each arguement value to the function we want to execute:

```
function setArguments(functionRef, args) {
    return args.length === 1
      ? functionRef
      : setArguments(functionRef(args[0]), args.slice(1))
}
```

#### Working Example

```js
function greet(word) {
  return function(name) {
    return word + ', ' + name + '.'
  }
}

var lookup = {
  greet: greet
}

function getFunction(lookup, name) {
  return lookup[name] || new Function()
}

function setArguments(functionRef, args) {
  return args.length === 1
    ? functionRef
    : setArguments(functionRef(args[0]), args.slice(1))
}

function executeFunctionByName(functionName, lookup, args) {
  var functionRef = getFunction(lookup, functionName)
  var functionRefWithArgs = setArguments(functionRef, args)
  return functionRefWithArgs(args[args.length - 1])
}

console.log(
  executeFunctionByName('greet', lookup, ['Hi', 'Jon'])
)
```